# roxygen2 not documenting a new project

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am trying to document a new R project using `roxygen2`. I am using `roxygen2` version 6.1.1 and `desc` version 1.2.0.

I have tried both the commands `roxygen2::roxygenise()` and `devtools::document()` but in both cases I am getting the same error:

```
Updating documentation 
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically... 
Error in if (any(mismatch <- res != res2)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have looked at the following issue: [roxygen new project issue](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/779) and tried following the advice of reinstalling both roxygen and desc to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's telling you that you have an error in your code. You likely need to change that line to `if (any(res != res2))`, but I don't have the full code so can't be completely sure. After you fix the error (and others that may pop up) it will let you continue.

Comment: @rpolicastro That is the roxygen2 code not mine. See the second last comment on the link in the question. That user got the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for blank lines in your DESCRIPTION file.

```
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "First",
           family = "Last",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "first.last@example.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
                                                       <- this line is blank, remove!
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
```

That solved the problem for me.